# Difference when executing a piece of code in main versus calling it as a function in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to do a CPU-intensive operation in GO. The code is pretty straight forward and I am trying to measure it as well. The measurement code looks like this

However, when I try to execute the same code as a function (invoked from main) it seems to work much faster. Any idea as to why this is happening?
package main

```
import (
       "fmt";
       "time"
    )


func addlist1 (from uint64, to uint64) {
var i uint64;   
var l uint64;   
var j uint64;   
var sum1 uint64;
var  count uint64;

   count = 0;
   for i=1;i<1001;i++ {
      for l=from;l<(from+to);l++ {
           j = l*l;
           count = count + 1;
           sum1 = sum1 + (j*j*j*j*j*j*j*j*j*j);
      }
   }
}


func main () {
   var sum1 uint64;
   var j uint64;
   var i uint64;
   var l uint64;
   var num uint64;
   var count  uint64;

   sum1 = 0;
   num = 100000000;
   start88 := time.Now ();
   addlist1(1,num);
   elapsed88 := time.Since(start88);
   fmt.Println("The time taken is ", elapsed88,sum1,num);
   time.Sleep(1*time.Second);

   sum1 = 0;
   count  = 0;
   start := time.Now();
   for i=1;i<1001;i++ {
      for l=1;l<num;l++ {
         j = l*l;
         sum1 = sum1 + (j*j*j*j*j*j*j*j*j*j);
         count = count+1;
      }
   }
   elapsed := time.Since(start);
   fmt.Println("The total time without function is", elapsed,sum1,num,count);
   time.Sleep(1*time.Second);

}
```

The first println gives an output of 29 seconds whereas the second one gives an output of 4m 57seconds. The difference is huge. It is consistent as well.

I am running this in a Debian distribution that has 4 cores.

Any ideas why this is so?

Sincerely,
Sudarsan.D

Comment: Your first function doesn’t do anything, it could be completely optimized away and still be valid.

Answer (score 2):

The code inside `main` and `addlist1` is **not the same.**

In the function `addlist1`, no values are returned. The compiler can completely optimize it away into nothing, because the function does nothing (it does not modify memory or return a value).

This is not true of the code in `main()`, which prints the value of `sum1`.

To make the code the same, return `sum1` and `count` from your function and print it from `main`:

```
func addlist1(from uint64, to uint64) (uint64, uint64) {
    ...
    return sum1, count
}

func main() {
    ...
    start := time.Now()
    sum, count := addlist1(1, num)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("The time taken is ", elapsed, sum1, num);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Did return the values, and now the timings are same. Thanks for your help.